# Unity transform.position question

Tags: unity, transformation

Looking at example code for mesh deformation in unity

https://answers.unity.com/questions/746673/sine-wave-mesh-deform-with-different-directions.html

And i see theyve used

```
 public Transform Target1;
 public Transform Target2;


 void CalculateWaves ()
 {
     waves[0].Direction = Target1.position - transform.position;
     waves[1].Direction = Target2.position - transform.position;
```

And i dont understand the difference between Target1.position and transform.position without any reference to an instance.

Arent they the same thing. And how does transform.position function without a reference.

Comment: Note that `Transform`, the class, is spelled with an uppercase T. When you see a lowercase t `transform` it's not referring to the class itself, but to a variable or property (generally one that's populated with an instance of the `Transform` class - see jhocking's answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword 'transform' by itself is equivalent to writing 'this.transform'. In other words, it's the transform of the object that the script is on.

Comment: Now that makes sense.